# how to send http tweet request in python

Tags: python, http, twitter

ive been scrolling though the twitter api documentation for a while now and I don't get it, it uses something called curl. turl and Idk if that's required but here it what the documents say,

the resource URL is : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json

```
curl -XPOST 
  --url 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=hello' 
  --header 'authorization: OAuth
  oauth_consumer_key="oauth_customer_key",
  oauth_nonce="generated_oauth_nonce",
  oauth_signature="generated_oauth_signature",
  oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_timestamp="generated_timestamp",
  oauth_token="oauth_token",
  oauth_version="1.0"'
```

and the twurl option is

```
 $ twurl -d 'status=Test tweet using the POST statuses/update endpoint' /1.1/statuses/update.json
```

and is there a way to make this work with python requests/ implement this with my existing python code or is there an easier way to do this in general, any help is appreciated

Comment: "is there a way to make this work with python requests"—sure. Just pull the relevant settings out of the `curl` command. It's pretty readable: `-XPOST` just means it's sending a POST request. And I hope that `--url` and `--header` are self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You an use this with Python requests or use the python-twitter API (https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or one of the other packages out there.

There are lots of libraries on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=twitter) to choose from, but if you really wanted, yes you could use Requests. Just send a POST request with the data that is required. See the documentation here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/